# Using CDATA in xml attribute?

Tags: xml, xcdatamodel

I wish to have an attribute in xml language, which content shouldn't be parsed.
It may contain javascript code, which probably contains many '&,|' and other operator types.
Im aware that the Text node can be a CDATA value, but how can I do the same behavior for attributes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't.

If you want to use characters with special meaning in an XML attribute value then you must use character references for those characters.